# Adding javax.validation capabilities to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, java-ee-6, bean-validation

I'm trying to run a web application using Tomcat but the the application is using libraries such as:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Future;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
```

These libraries are not part of the Tomcat spec so I need to add them manually.

What libraries should I add?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `javax.validation` package is a [Bean Validation (JSR-303)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) library.

An implementation of this specification is i.e. the [**Hibernate Validator**](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) or the [**Apache Bean Validation**](https://bval.apache.org/).

Comment: Hibernate Validator or the Apache Bean Validation do not seem to have an implementation of these classes - import javax.validation.constraints.Future;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size; bean-validator.jar from glassfish3 server does. Have you used these packages before with Hibernate Validator or the Apache Bean Validation ?

Comment: Hibernate Validator consists of Bean Validation API in "/hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final/lib/required/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar" which defines javax.validation.* packages.

Answer (score 0):

but for Size and NotNull you need http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbeanvalidatorjar.htm